# Reverse to the power of

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

In Unity or pseudocode, how would I reverse the following calculation which goes from a given value over 1 to a modifiedValue ...

```
// value can be anything that's > 1f and <= 2f
float power = Mathf.Pow(value, 2f) * 2f;
float modifiedValue = Mathf.Pow(value, power);
```

... to turn a given modifiedValue into the original value again? (I perhaps need to have a power be 1f / something somewhere, but not sure exactly.) Thanks!

Comment: Looks more like a math problem.

Comment: [There are no simple solutions](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxCE4P6csNbrC1rYsTsNIqyzOSFOnLPb/fwA), so look for a numerical one.

Comment: @user202729 link doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: [As it increases monotonically, you can use binary search](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+v%5E(2*v%5E2)+for+v+from+1+to+2).

Comment: There's only below 100ish possible values (it's a UI slider), so if all else fails I can try create a lookup table to reverse. Guess I had figured it would be a straighforward math reversal, but if not that would work.

Comment: So, starting from `y = f(x) = x ^ (2x^2)` you want to find the inverse function `g(y) = f^-1(x)`?

Comment: Will a slider give you enough control for a function that grows that fast? Where does the function come from?

Comment: Arndt, yes the slider is working and works intuitively (for the need of our app). It goes from 0 - 2 max in its original value, and above functionality is applied for any original value > 1 (so it grows up to 256 roughly -- which is object scale x256 -- but allows finer tuning at lower levels). But as we only store the resulting value, we need to set the slider back to position upon loading, too.

Comment: Galandil, I might not be able to answer with a simple yes or no, though I can tell you if it works once I pop a solution into our app, sorry!

Comment: Could you use a different function? x^8 would also bound the values from 1 to 256, with the same fine tuning for low values and it would be way simpler to solve for

Comment: @user202729 It's working now, it may have just been a caching error on my end. Sorry!

Comment: Basile, thanks, I've just tried ^8, but that will cause a different curve, and not allow as much fine tuning at the start (the curve won't be as flat at the start anymore, so it will jump to higher values too soon).

Comment: This simplification might work, though: Mathf.Pow( value, Mathf.Pow(value, 3f) )

Comment: @PhilippLenssen That's not easily revertible either. In general, most functions `value -> expr` where `value` appears more than once in `expr` are hard to reverse.

Comment: Thank you, that's very educative!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving for the original value would involve complex numbers. Here is the math from [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20%3D%20x%5E(2*(x%5E2))%20solve%20x)

[image]

Since you say this is for a UI slider, it is clear that doing the computation is overkill. Here are two solutions:

- Use a function that gives the same advantages. `value^8` is a good candidate: bounds the values from 1 to 256, with the same fine tuning for low values. Reverting it is easy using `modifiedValue^(1/8)`
- Use a lookup table.

Choosing between these is a metter of preferences. My advice would be: If you are flexible on the function, use the first solution. the code will be cleaner and it will be easy to change the function later. Otherwise use the lookup table

Comment: Many thanks! The curve for value^8 is not as flat as needed at the start for finetuning (I've just tried in the UI, but also overlaid the two curves in Wolfram). However, Mathf.Pow( value, Mathf.Pow(value, 3f) ) gets reasonably close to what I want -- maybe that can be reversed easier (without yet using a lookup table)?

Comment: when you enter it in wolfram, it will tell you how to solve for it (you can see it in the link in my answer). I think that any solution with `value` somewhere in the right argument of the `Pow` function will be difficult to revert.

Comment: "In general, most functions value -> expr where value appears more than once in expr are hard to reverse." -- For example, `value -> Pow(2, value)` has an inverse `value -> Log(2, value)`.

Comment: Thank you. I will go for an auto-calculated lookup table with 1000 steps where I'll pick a smallest-difference match from during modifiedValue to value loading.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Why don't you use a binary search?

Comment: I've now implemented Dictionary<float,float> sliderValueToScale, and for what it's worth it works fine. How would I go about binary search approach in Unity, data-structure and function wise? Thanks!